# turtlebot 2 movement

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Ros community, Has anyone successfully implemented python code or lunch file for moving the turtlebot 2 in spiral pattern or any specific pattern ?
could someone guide me , Iam new in Ros . Please help me.
thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/280754/turtlebot-2-movement/) by [karmel](https://answers.ros.org/users/33415/karmel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-01-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-01-24**:\

> I have tried everything

What does that mean? Please be specific and give (code) examples.

**Comment by [lagankapoor](https://answers.ros.org/users/33282/lagankapoor/) on 2018-01-25**:
Are you need turtlebot code ? and in python ?

**Comment by [karmel](https://answers.ros.org/users/33415/karmel/) on 2018-01-25**:
yes exactly, please if you have any one .

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-01-25**:
What have you tried so far? This site is about helping people, not doing their homework.

**Comment by [karmel](https://answers.ros.org/users/33415/karmel/) on 2018-01-25**:
yah , i know i want any help or any example just if you can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

check this link :-

http://learn.turtlebot.com/

'http://learn.turtlebot.com/'

---

Originally posted by [lagankapoor](https://answers.ros.org/users/33282/lagankapoor/) with karma: 216 on 2018-01-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [karmel](https://answers.ros.org/users/33415/karmel/) on 2018-01-26**:
thanks, i will see it

**Comment by [lagankapoor](https://answers.ros.org/users/33282/lagankapoor/) on 2018-01-29**:
welcome you